# How do I get timezone information of out-of-office/VacationSettings start/endTime?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Gmail API request [users.settings.getVacation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/getVacation)

```
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/getVacation?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D
```

returns both start and end time in epoch ms. However these int64 numbers are timezone specific, but there is no timezone info included.

How do I get correct 'midnight' dates?

For example, these are values for user in GMT+0200 timezone

```
  "enableAutoReply": false,
  "responseSubject": "OOF",
  "responseBodyHtml": "OOF",
  "restrictToContacts": false,
  "restrictToDomain": false,
  "startTime": "1630188000000",
  "endTime": "1630879200000"
}
```

which translates in `Sat Aug 28 2021 22:00:00 GMT+0000` / `Sun Aug 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200`

Comment: I would assume that the timezone would be that of the current user.  Have you checked their profile?

Comment: I somehow found out, that current operation system time zone is used when user submits Gmail UI out-of-office settings.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: Just by trying to change OS timezone and saving the out-of-office Gmail form. And after each save by getting VacationSettings values from API.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately there's no such parameter in Gmail API nor Directory API to retrieve this information.

What you can do instead is to file a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107).

However, the `startTime` and `endTime` parameters return the UTC time corresponding to the midnight.

Comment: They seem not to be recalculated to UTC midnight. Just quick test: set OS timezone to something else than UTC (in my case GMT+0100, or +0200 now in summer DST), save Gmail out-of-office form with start set to 31.8.2021 and API reply is "startTime" : "1630360800000" which corresponds to 30.8.2021 22:00 and not 31.8.2021 00:00.